# Facebook to tell that a friend that also works in same workplace?

Tags: facebook

When adding a workplace, we have the popup window that allow to add friends who also work there as attached snapshot. I want to add more friends but it seems to be nowhere for us to do so i.e. the popup shown only once when adding workplace.

So I ask here, how to add more Facebook friends to a workplace?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on *edit* from dropdown in that workplace where do you want add more friends. Change the audience and click on Save Changes, you will get that popup window, select you friend and save this.

Something here to note, changing audience means if you have set it friends, change it public or if you have set it public, change it to friends. Later you can change your audience anytime.

To see that popup window, do this process after some interval. After first change it will show but immediately if you make changes again it will not show.

Comment: I'll try and let you know when done.

Comment: Do you know if changing audience triggers notification for friends?

Comment: No, It will not trigger any notification for friends.